# Build Permissions for Queue New Build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am trying to lock down our build and deployment configuration to production to only allow build administrators access to do this.  I thought what I'd do is Deny Contributors and My Team queue build access.

I am a part of the contributors group as well, however when I tried to kick off this build it is  saying access is denied.

What might I be doing wrong so that I can build and deploy to production with the build administrators group by denying constributors this ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit deny permissions take precedence over all other explicitly or implicitly set permissions.

If you want to deny all users access to something by default, clear any explicit allows so that the permission is "Not Set". "Not Set" is an implicit deny. Then, you can add explicit "Allow" permissions as necessary for the users or groups you want to have access.

Comment: Daniel, I tried that.  After reading online the problem is that if you are in two separate groups TFS will take the least amount of privilege.  So I denied contributors and kept build administrators the same.  Even though I was in both it still denied me the ability to run the build.  I just to adjust the groups better.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding. From the documentation: "TFS uses a least-permissive model for security permissions. What that means is that **if a user belongs to two groups and the same permission is assigned Allow for one group and Deny for another group, Deny takes precedence over Allow.** There are a few exceptions to this rule for those who belong to the Project Collection Administrator and Team Foundation Server Administrator groups."

Comment: I understand.  If my comment was clear on that I apologize.  I got it to work how I wanted by moving the users around to different TFS groups and then adjusting the security on the one build definition I wanted to make sure developers could not queue.